# Converting between SQL char and C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I want to insert into a database column of type char(2) from C#. 
What data type would I use in C#?

If using the following code:

```
private static SqlParameter addParameterValue(string parameterName, ? parameterValue, SqlCommand command)
    {
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(parameterName, SqlDbType.Char);
        parameter.Value = parameterValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        return parameter;
    }
```

What type would I give to parameterValue?

I already have method like this when the parameterValue is of type string, so this could be a problem when telling the difference between SqlDbType.Char and SqlDbType.Varchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` will work fine if it is 2 characters or shorter

Comment: So just need to do a length check on the string?

Comment: I think that SQL will throw an exception along the lines of 'string or binary data would be truncated' rather than automatically truncating. Depends on the setup I suppose

Answer (score 10):

`char`, `varchar`, `nchar`, `nvarchar` are actually strings

the `size` helps to determine how long the string is...

**by the way**

`char` has a fixed length, so if you want to have `"1"` in a `char(2)` the contents will be actual `"1 "`

`varchar(2)` will be `"1"`

the `n` part stands for unicode, so everything inside those fields will be in Unicode.

---

**normally** we use `nvarchar` to save some space on the data, as if you have a `char(250)` the database will always save the full length, as an empty `varchar(250)` will be nothing.

In our programming language we then use padding to do what `char` does, for example, in C#

```
"1".PadLeft(2);
"1".PadRight(2);
```

will output `" 1"` and `"1 "` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

try using AddWithValue method and parce it as string,

it is only a one line. no need to have a seperate method.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName, parameterValue);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this has shortened my code slightly. Although I inherited this method.